# How to extract data from GPX file (and to parse gpx file)?

Tags: xml, gpx, xmllint

I am coding in bash under Linux. I am trying to extract the *track name* and the *first timestamp* of each track in series of gpx files.

I have tried to parse the gpx file with xmllint with the following commands (and other variations):

```
xmllint --xpath "//gpx/trk/name/text()" test.gpx
xmllint --xpath "//gpx/trk/trkseg[1]/time/text()" test.gpx
```

It failed with a return message: `XPath set is empty`

Here is a example of the file *test.gpx*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<gpx creator="www.flyisfun.com" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
  <trk>
    <name>Track_n1</name>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="-48.843895" lon="10.9835696">
        <ele>126.75549</ele>
        <time>2016-04-16T11:05:00Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="-48.843254" lon="11.9823042">
        <ele>126.90486</ele>
        <time>2016-04-16T11:05:05Z</time>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

I was expecting to get for the this test case

```
Track_n1
2016-04-16T11:05:00Z
```

I would like to know why the commands with xmllint are not working and if I can adjust them to work without altering the original gpx files.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're open to an alternative to xmllint, [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) is a good one. There are quite a few commands in xmlstarlet, but for just querying data [`sel` (select)](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416) will do.

I like how you can either bind namespaces to prefixes or use `_` for the prefix of the default namespace (in version 1.5.0+). [See here for more details.](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139530992) I prefer this over piping echo to xmllint.

Example of binding default namespace to prefix...

```
xmlstarlet sel -N g="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" -t -m "/g:gpx/g:trk" -v "g:name" -n -v "g:trkseg/g:trkpt[1]/g:time" -n test.gpx
```

Example of using `_` as the prefix of the default namespace...

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/_:gpx/_:trk" -v "_:name" -n -v "_:trkseg/_:trkpt[1]/_:time" -n test.gpx
```

Both of the examples above produce the following output...

```
Track_n1
2016-04-16T11:05:00Z
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and the example for xmlstarlet. I used your solution:  I found the syntax is easier to understand and to generalize.

Answer (score 1):

XML sample contains a default namespace `xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"`. `xmllint --shell` in combination with `setns` can be used to get the values.
Changing a default (empty) namespace to a known one:

```
echo -e 'setns ns=http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1\ncat //ns:gpx/ns:trk/ns:name/text()' \
| xmllint --shell test.xml | grep -Ev '^([/]| [-])'
```

Result:

```
Track_n1
```

`local-name()`xml function can be used too but gives complex xpath expressions hard to read sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to be able to convert my Garmin GPX to text format from the solutions given here. Here are some working syntaxes:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N g="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" -T -t -m "/g:gpx/g:trk/g:trkseg/g:trkpt" -v "@lat" -o "|" -v "@lon" -o "|" -v "g:ele" -o "|" -v "g:time" -n my_track.gpx

xmlstarlet sel -N g="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" -T -t -m "/g:gpx/g:trk/g:trkseg/g:trkpt" -v "concat(@lat,'|',@lon,'|',g:ele,'|',g:time)" -n my_track.gpx

xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "/_:gpx/_:trk/_:trkseg/_:trkpt" -v "concat(@lat,'|',@lon,'|',_:ele,'|',_:time)" -n my_track.gpx

xmlstarlet select --text --template --match "/_:gpx/_:trk/_:trkseg/_:trkpt" --value-of "concat(@lat,'|',@lon,'|',_:ele,'|',_:time)" --nl my_track.gpx
```

Answer (score 0):

Also possible to solve using perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343636/from-gpx-to-csv-file

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

    my $xml = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile('my_track.gpx'); 

foreach my $wpt ( $xml -> get_xpath('/gpx/trk/trkseg/trkpt') ) {
     print $wpt -> att('lat') . "|" . $wpt -> att('lon') . "|" . $wpt -> first_child_text('ele') . "|" . $wpt -> first_child_text('time') . "\n";
}
```